# How many shapes with Euler characteristic 2 of which all faces border the same amount of faces (through edges and vertexes combined)?

Tags: geometry, spheres, tessellations

I'm trying to create a shape that I can map to both a plane and a sphere.

I don't care about distortions at all, so, for example, platonic solids work. However, I need a solution that works for a large amount of tiles, preferably arbitrarily large. Hosohedra satisfy this criteria, but they only tile in one direction, and ideally I would want to have different tiles for different latitudes as well.

I'm aware that this is likely impossible without making some sort of compromise somewhere, but I figured I might as well ask those who specialise in this sort of thing.

Comment: "all faces border the same amount of faces" just means all faces are triangles, or all faces are quadrilaterals, or all faces are pentagons, or all faces are hexagons (it stops there – the faces can't all be heptagons, or octogons, and so on). "through edges and vertices combined," that part I don't understand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If I subdivide a rhombicuboctahedron in a particular way I can get it so that all faces border the same amount of faces through edges, but not through edges and vertices combined.

[Here's an example.](http://puu.sh/yOwm8/4b09fadd26.jpg)

All faces are quadrilaterals, but they are put together in an unconventional way. (Don't mind the bottom by the way, I accidentally took a pseudo-rhombicuboctahedron. It doesn't matter for the example.)

Comment: OK, so I understand that faces are allowed to meet other faces along part of an edge, not just along a whole edge. But I still don't know what you mean by "through edges and vertices combined".

Comment: @GerryMyerson [Here's another image](http://puu.sh/yOxzV/07f49b2214.png) to illustrate what I mean.  

On the first one, faces that touch the indicated face through an edge or vertex are counted as bordering. In the second, it's only through edges. This is what I mean. I'm looking for the former to always be equal.

Comment: Also, where faces meet along part of an edge, the point between them is turned into a vertex with a 180 degree angle, making the apparent triangles into quadrilaterals.

Comment: OK, now I understand. It's an odd way to count, though, so I'm not sure whether anyone has thought about it much.